# Unable to view the content in listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments

I am using a list view in fragment which loads data using json in that i cannot able to view the list view.In the sched it shows the constructor is never used i don't know where i have done wrong in the code.The server part works fine.

Fragment:

```
public class SchedulessFragment extends Fragment{
private static final String TAG = MatAct.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String url = "http://nammakovai2015-001-site1.1tempurl.com/iplspin/schedules.php";
ProgressDialog pDialog;
List<Sched> movieList = new ArrayList<Sched>();
ListView listview;
CustomListAdapter adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_frag, container, false);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    //  TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvfrag);
    //    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));
    //   tv.setText("Hello");
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color


    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Sched m = new Sched();
                            m.setTeama(obj.getString("teama"));

                            m.setTeamb(obj.getString("teamb"));
                            m.setTdate(obj.getString("tdate"));
                            m.setTtime(obj.getString("ttime"));
                           m.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("thumbnailUrl"));
                            m.setTeambthumbnailUrl(obj.getString("teambthumbnailUrl"));
                            m.setVenue(obj.getString("venue"));


                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(m);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    return v;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
public static SchedulessFragment newInstance(String text) {

    SchedulessFragment f = new SchedulessFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}}
```

ListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
 List<Sched> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Sched> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_ros, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.pict);
    NetworkImageView teambthumbnail=(NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pict1);
    TextView teama = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleteama_name);
    TextView teamb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.schduleteamb_name);
    TextView tdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datess);
    TextView ttime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timess);
    TextView venue=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.schedulevenue);
    // getting movie data for the row
    Sched m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    teambthumbnail.setImageUrl(m.getTeambthumbnailUrl(),imageLoader);
    // title
    teama.setText(m.getTeama());
    teamb.setText(m.getTeamb());
    tdate.setText(m.getTdate());
    ttime.setText(m.getTtime());
    venue.setText(m.getVenue());


    return convertView;
}}
```

Sched:

```
public class Sched {
private String teama,teamb,tdate,ttime,thumbnailUrl,teambthumbnailUrl,venue;

public Sched(){}

public Sched(String teama, String teamb, String tdate, String ttime, String thumbnailUrl, String teambthumbnailurl, String venue)
{
    this.teama=teama;
    this.teamb=teamb;
    this.tdate=tdate;
    this.ttime=ttime;
    this.thumbnailUrl=thumbnailUrl;
    this.teambthumbnailUrl=teambthumbnailurl;
    this.venue=venue;


}


public String getTeama(){
    return teama;
}
public void setTeama(String teama){
    this.teama=teama;
}
public String getTeamb(){
    return teamb;
}
public void setTeamb(String teamb){
    this.teamb=teamb;
}

public String getTdate(){
    return tdate;
}
public void setTdate(String tdate){
    this.tdate=tdate;
}
public String getTtime(){
    return ttime;
}
public void setTtime(String ttime){
    this.ttime=ttime;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}
public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}
public String getTeambthumbnailUrl() {
    return teambthumbnailUrl;
}
public void setTeambthumbnailUrl(String teambthumbnailUrl){
    this.teambthumbnailUrl=teambthumbnailUrl;
}
public String getVenue(){
    return venue;
}
public void setVenue(String venue){
    this.venue=venue;
}}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
   >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/tvfrag"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="219dp" />
```

Comment: because when you are coming to the first tym ,then your arraylist is null, and setting the adapter ,either you set the adapter when your data is filled in the arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating the adapter before the `movieList` has been populated. Move these two lines:

```
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

after the for loop in which you're adding the Movies to the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Sched m = new Sched();
                        m.setTeama(obj.getString("teama"));

                        m.setTeamb(obj.getString("teamb"));
                        m.setTdate(obj.getString("tdate"));
                        m.setTtime(obj.getString("ttime"));
                       m.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("thumbnailUrl"));
                        m.setTeambthumbnailUrl(obj.getString("teambthumbnailUrl"));
                        m.setVenue(obj.getString("venue"));


                        // adding movie to movies array
                        movieList.add(m);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//PUT THOSE TWO LINES HERE
```

Assuming your `Request` is good and it returns a non-empty `JSONArray`, this should work.

Comment: No it didn't works and if u notice the Sched file which i have given above in that the constructor is never used i thing does it makes any problem.                                                                                           public Sched(String teama, String teamb, String tdate, String ttime, String thumbnailUrl, String teambthumbnailurl, String venue)
{
    this.teama=teama;
    this.teamb=teamb;
    this.tdate=tdate;
    this.ttime=ttime;
    this.thumbnailUrl=thumbnailUrl;
    this.teambthumbnailUrl=teambthumbnailurl;
    this.venue=venue;


}

Comment: You have 2 constructors, of course the one with the parameters isn't used because you're using the **empty** constructor only.

Comment: even it doesn't show the listview it shows only a white screen

Comment: Well the white screen IS what the empty listview looks like :) unless you change it by setting `listview.setEmptyView(R.id.empty)`. Try using the constructor with parameters instead of the empty one and also go into the **debug** mode and check if your response is empty. If it's not, then your logic is faulty somewhere.

Comment: how to use the parametered constructor can u tell it bcoz  i am a newbie

Comment: Instead of doing `new Sched()`, do `new Sched(obj.getString("teama"), obj.getString("teamb"), ... , ... , ...)` and this way for every parameter the constructor expects to get. This is just Java 101.